# Entity in the API project has UserId how do I get, the username from IdentityServer4?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a .NET Core API that has an `Artist.cs` entity. This application has no Authentication or Authorization logic. All that is delegated to IdentityServer4 coupled with ASP.NET Identity.

```
    public class Artist
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

I wish to have an endpoint on my API that shows the most recent submissions `/artists/latest` with a response like:

```
[
    {
        "artist": "Ray Charles",
        "username": "John Doe"
    },
    {
        "artist": "BB King",
        "username": "Mary"
    }
]
```

The problem is, my API database does not have the username! It only stores the user Id. How do I get the username from the UserId?

Comment: Then where is the Username stored? Are you using the Microsoft Identity Core?

Comment: Sorry, yep IdentityServer4 is coupled with Identity.

Comment: Edit the question and list down the process you are following. This question lacks basic information like which technology it is using and which version.

Comment: So, you don't want the logged-in user's information. You want the information of the user id connected to the artist. Right?

Comment: Exactly! Yep, there is no logged in user.

Comment: I've updated the question like you asked. Thanks @KishanVaishnav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access Username (Data stored in another database) from a different API.

Let's get some things straight. There are three different apps involved in this scenario.

1. Identity Server: An MVC app or API which is responsible for providing the access_token.
2. Resource Owner: The API which provides services related to the user info.
3. Client: The API, which is trying to access the user info.

Here, the Identity Server and Resource Owner can be the same app in some cases.

There are two ways you can achieve it.

**API way**

- Create an endpoint `users\{userId}` on the Resource Owner API.
- Create a client on the Identity Server with Client Credential grant type. Which enables the machine to machine access.
- Setup Identity Server on Resource Owner API with the client_id and client_secret configured in the Identity Server.
- When the Client API receives a request on `/artists/latest` endpoint. It needs access to the information of the user `x`

  1. It sends a HTTP request to the Identity server and saves token(`xyz`) from the response somewhere so it can reuse it in the current request.
  2. Then sends a new HTTP request to the Resource Owner API. like `www.my-api.com/api/users/x` with the token as `Authorizatoin: Bearer xyz`. And from the response, it retrieves the required info.

You can also make an endpoint where you can send a list of user id and it returns list of user info.

**Database way**

*The other way (Simpler way IMO)*

If you have data access layer in place then you can just add it as a dependency of the Client API and use it directly.

If you don't have a DAL then you can just create a library and paste the DBContext in it then reuse it in any project you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why that application doesn't have Authorization?

When you generate the token on IdentityServer, the client must ask for "profile" scope, and IdentityServer must allow it.

Then you will have access to the following profile claims:

- **name**
- family_name
- given_name
- middle_name
- nickname
- preferred_username
- profile
- picture
- website
- gender
- birthdate
- zoneinfo
- locale
- updated_at

**Just make sure when you are creating users you are creating the "name" claim**.
When your API receives the access token, you can access the "name" claim.

Comment: His question is wrong. Read it again. He wants Artist API to get user info from other API.

Comment: oh ok, then your two approaches API way or DB way makes more sense. I tought he could had a token with the user info